# WAVE accessibility tool: Very small text - is it possible to avoid this warning, but keep the font size unchanged?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wave

There is a piece of code that shows tiny "8px text" on the page instead of bootstrap icon.

```
<a href="someurl"><span class="small-text-as-an-image">8px text</span></a>
```

This text should not be treated as a text for eyes, but please treat it as an image.

How to avoid WAVE accessibility warning that this text is very small?

1. The first option is to make this text as an image. JPEG or whatever image. Is it good? I don't think so.
2. The second option is to use css preudoclass + apply

   .small-text-as-an-image:after {
           content: "8px text";
   }

Looks like the second option would be the way to go (tested with JAWS as well, seems like JAWS respects this solution as well and pronounces it).

However this solution is also not perfect as far as translating the web site into 2+ languages will cause issues: the text should be avoided in css where possible.

Any good solution that WAVE accessibility tool will avoid this warning and also readers read it as "8px text"?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a _warning_ only, so there should be no need to “avoid” it in the first place. There is nothing wrong with deciding to _ignore_ a warning, if there is good enough reason for it. Such tools are meant to help you spot _potential_ issues, they are not a god-like entity that you had to “please” at all cost.

Comment: _“However this solution is also not perfect as far as translating the web site into 2+ languages will cause issues”_ - if it doesn’t have to be _readable_ text to begin with, then how can translation become an issue?

Comment: @misorude please treat it as another "image" should be displayed for people from another countries. Like a small text on the small coat of arms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <a href="someurl"><span class="small-text-as-an-image">8px text</span></a>
> ```
>
> This text should not be treated as a text for eyes, but please treat it as an image.

**This text is the only content inside a link**. So it can't be treated as a decorative image

- it lacks some alternative (using `aria-label` for instance),
- it should be perceivable
- it might be large enough to be clickable (using CSS) (see [target size](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/target-size.html))